# volume of solid around y axis rotation

Tags: calculus

I am working on this problem and need some help figuring it out. I will give the problem and then give the ways i tried to solve it:

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region inside the circle $x^2+y^2=16$ and to the right of the line $x=3$ about the $y$ axis.

I know that the circle has the radius of $4$, so since i am going around the $y$ axis I originally used $x$ in terms of $y$ and integrated $\pi r^2$ from $0$ to $4$ using the radius of $\sqrt{16-y^2}$. I knew this was wrong, so I instead did $2\pi x \sqrt{16-x^2}$ and did from $0$ to $4$ but still I only got $\dfrac{128\pi}{3}$ for each one.

Can anyone walk me through it and show me how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do this by the cylindrical shell method integrating from $x=3$ to $x=4$ using

\begin{equation}
A=\int_3^42\pi rh\,dx
\end{equation}

where $r=x$ and $h=2\sqrt{16-x^2}$. Use the substitution $u=\sqrt{16-x^2}$.